# Redisplay Form with drop down PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, display

I know my query is reasonably well documented but I'm still not sure so wondering if someone could weigh in here: I have a drop down field either 'html' or 'plain'.

See code:

```
       $mail_format = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['mformat'])) {
        $form_is_submitted = true;
        if ($mail_format == 'plain' || $mail_format == 'html') {
            $clean['mformat'] = $_POST['mformat'];
        } else {
            $errors['mformat'] = '***You have not ticked a format***';
            $errors_detected = true;
        }
    if(isset($errors['mformat'])) {
    $mformat_2 = $errors['mformat'];
} else {
    $mformat_2 = '';
}

    if (isset($clean['mformat'])) {
    $mail_format = $clean['mformat'];
} else {
    $mail_format = '';
}
            <label for="mform">Mail format</label>
                        <select name="mformat" id="mform">
                            <option value="plain">Plain text</option>
                            <option value="html">HTML</option>
                        </select>
```

If the user does not tick a format, how do I register the error next to the field with the message above? Equally if they do tick a format but other fields are wrong, how do I get it to redisplay to the form the option the user selected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you not using `<form>` tags with a post method?

Comment: Yes indeed I'm using form tags with a post method back to $ server global array but thought I'd leave all that out and get to the code that needs to be configured...

Answer (score 0):

That script has some problems, you're not assigning `$mail_format` and your variable names should be clearer, but to answer your general question, you can just write the error message variable to the page

```
<div class="error"><?php echo $mail_format_error_msg;?></div>
<select name="mail_format" id="mail_format">
    <option value="plain">Plain text</option>
    <option value="html">HTML</option>
</select>
```

To persist the users selection, you need to dynamically write the `selected` attribute. Like this:

```
<option value="plain" <?php if (isset($mail_format) && $mail_format=="plain") echo "selected";?>>Plain text</option>
<option value="html" <?php if (isset($mail_format) && $mail_format=="html") echo "selected";?>>HTML</option>
```

Comment: Thanks! To assign $mail_format, when I code: $mail_format = $_POST['mformat'];, it errors out saying undefined index: mformat. Also, with <? php echo mformat_2; ?> it doesn't provide the error.

Comment: My example is how it's generally done -- not a replacement for you learning basic PHP.